# JavaScript arrays passed by reference or value?

Tags: javascript

I have a little confusion as to how arrays are handled when passed to functions. 
My question is why does the ouput of sample2.js NOT be null ?

```
// sample1.js======================================
// This clearly demonstrates that the array was passed by reference
function foo(o) {
  o[1] = 100;
}

var myArray = [1,2,3];
console.log(myArray);  // o/p : [1,2,3]
foo(myArray);
console.log(myArray); // o/p : [1,100,3]




//sample2.js =====================================
// upon return from bar, myArray2 is not set to null.. why so
function bar(o) {
  o = null;
}

var myArray2 = [1,2,3];
console.log(myArray2);  // o/p : [1,2,3]
bar(myArray2);
console.log(myArray2); // o/p : [1,100,3]
```

Comment: By reference. Only primitive types passed by value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variables pointing to arrays only ever contain references. Those references are copied.

In `bar`, `o` and `myArray2` are both references to the same array. `o` is not a reference to the `myArray2` variable.

Inside the function, you are overwriting the value of `o` (a reference to the array) with a new value (`null`).

You aren't following the reference and then assigning `null` to the memory space where the array exists.

Answer (score 0):

An visual example of what Quentin said many years ago. In other words, references to arrays create new arrays, but the new arrays contain references to the original array's values.

```js
function updateArray (arrayOfRefs) {
      let arrayInternal = arrayOfRefs;
      arrayInternal[1] = 100;  // or a value like null
      arrayInternal = null;  // null this reference array (not the external original)
      arrayOfRefs[1] -= 1;  // proves both refs were to same external value
      arrayOfRefs[2] = null;
}

var externalArray = [1,2,3];  console.log(externalArray);
updateArray (externalArray);  console.log(externalArray);
```